# Logstash: grok expression for multiline data

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am new to ELK stack. I am trying to write one grok expression for the following log statement

```
2017-10-26 19:20:28.538 ERROR --- [logAppenderService] [Serv01] [restartedMain] ns.pcs.log.appender.LogAppender : [1234] doStuff Some statement here - {} 
java.lang.Exception: Hello World 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I have written the following logstash configuration:

```
    input{
            kafka {
                    type => "mylog"
                    topic_id => 'mylog'
            }

    }
filter{
            if [type] == "mylog" {

                grok {

                        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} \[%{DATA:serviceName}] \[%{DATA:nodeName}] \[%{DATA:trName}] %{NOTSPACE:className} %{NOTSPACE:':'} \[%{DATA:refName}] %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }

                } 
        }
}

output{
        if [type] == "mylog" {
            elasticsearch {

                hosts => ["101.18.19.89:9200"]
                index => "logstash-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
            }
        } 
        stdout {
           codec => rubydebug
        }

}
```

When I am trying to run the same I am getting json parse exception. Not sure if I am missing something or not. I am really stuck at this stage.

Comment: Your configuration is missing the `filter {}` around the `if [type] == "mylog" {}`

Comment: sorry. It's my mistake. I actually deleted accidentally while pasting the same here. I am modifying the original post

Comment: @baudsp I have modified the original post.

Comment: Ok. But I don't understand how you are getting a json parsing error when you don't have any json filter/codec in your configuration. Perhaps you put in your question the whole error message.

Comment: @baudsp I think the json parsing error is the logline to be parsed by grok, not an error produced by grok.

Comment: So the problem is not with grok, but with json. Update your question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the input is not matching in your pattern

Please try this

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} --- \[%{DATA:serviceName}\] \[%{DATA:nodeName}\] \[%{DATA:trName}\] %{NOTSPACE:className} %{NOTSPACE:':'} \[%{DATA:refName}] %{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

you missing the

> ---
>
> ]

pattern

if you still can't please check the mutiline is sending into your log

you could add the mutiline into your input if needed

```
codec => multiline {
        pattern => "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[\.,][0-9]{3,7} "
        negate => true
        what => "previous"
        }
```